# What is the difference between mount and mount -o loop

Tags: mount, loop-device

I have a iso file named `ubuntu.iso`.

I can `mount` it with the command: `mount ubuntu.iso /mnt`. After mounting it, I can see it from the outout of the command `df -h`: `/dev/loop0      825M  825M     0 100% /mnt`.

However, if I execute the command `mount -o loop ubuntu.iso /mnt`, I'll get the same result.

As I know, loop device allows us to visit the iso file as a device, I think this is why we add the option `-o loop`. But I can visit my iso file even if I only execute `mount ubuntu.iso /mnt`.

So I can't see the difference between `mount` and `mount -o loop`.

Comment: Also a important thing is sometimes mount can't setup loopback device with appropriate arugments For example:`mount ubuntu.iso /mnt` it do not setup a read-only loopback device,and `mount /image.squashfs /mnt` it do not setup a `DIO`(`losetup --direct-io=on`)loopback device.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Both versions use loop devices, and produce the same result; the short version relies on “cleverness” added to `mount` in recent years. `mount -o loop` tells `mount` explicitly to use a loop device; it leaves the loop device itself up to `mount`, which will look for an available device, set it up, and use that. (You can specify the device too with *e.g.* `mount -o loop=/dev/loop1`.)

The cleverness is that, when given a file to mount, `mount` will automatically use a loop device to mount it when necessary — *i.e.*, the file system isn’t specified, or `libblkid` determines that the file system is only supported on block devices (and therefore a loop device is needed to translate the file into a block device).

[The loop device section of the `mount` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#THE_LOOP_DEVICE) has more details.

Comment: Not *that * long ago there was no "-o loop" option in mount either and you would have to manually create the loop device with losetup command.

Comment: @Edheldil that depends on your notion of “long ago” ;-). `util-linux` 2.11 supported `mount -o loop` in 2001, and I think 2.10 had it too, at least a year earlier.

Comment: Yeah, but did commonly used stable distributions in 2001 use util-linux 2.11 already?

Comment: @rackandboneman I went digging a bit more, and it turns out that support for `-o loop` was added sometime between `util-linux` 2.4 and 2.5j; Debian 1.1 [had the latter](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian-1.1/main/binary-i386/base/) and was released in June 1996. So this option has been available in distributions for over twenty years.

Comment: An advantage to this cleverness: if/when XFS developers' new "direct file mount" feature (without the need for loop devices) reaches the kernel, `mount` will be able to switch to that mechanism transparently _(At least for the first 15 minutes until it turns out it broke somebody's shellscript and everyone has to go back to loop devices)_, unlike `mount -o loop` which still explicitly asks for the old (current) mechanism.

Answer (score 13):

The `loop` device is primarily controlled with the `losteup` command. So `losetup -a` gives you overview about the used loop devices and attached files. The `mount` command can mount the **block device only**. The loop device can create the virtual block device from a file (character device).

In fact there is a great difference between those commands because on older Linux systems the `mount` could not recognise the *file* as the correct device to be mounted, but during the time the mount command was completed with lot of feature, hence it can now self decide to try to call the losetup command and mount the result. But if you got a whole disk image not iso format but e.g. with MBR at the beginning, the mount command could not recognise it and you have to find the usable partition (e.g. with the `parted disk_image.raw unit B print` command) yoursef and than mount it with full option mount comman as :

```
mount disk_image.raw /mntpoint/ -o loop,offset=${OFFSET_of_PARTITION}
```

In this syntax the loop device was not specified and it is assumed the system choose the first free (`/dev/loop0`, `/dev/loop1` etc)
Among the other new features of mount command is that you need not specify the filesystem type of the mounted block device (in your case `-t iso9660`) if the filesystem support was installed.

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference between `mount ubuntu.iso /mnt` and `mount -o loop ubuntu.iso /mnt`.

The first is transparently handled as if you had used the second.