# What are these empty 0B SIZE read-write loop devices?

Tags: loop-device, lsblk

What are these empty (`0B` `SIZE`) read-write `loop` devices?

```
sudo lsblk --all
```

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0    0B  0 loop 
loop1    7:1    0    0B  0 loop 
loop2    7:2    0    0B  0 loop 
loop3    7:3    0    0B  0 loop 
loop4    7:4    0    0B  0 loop 
loop5    7:5    0    0B  0 loop 
loop6    7:6    0    0B  0 loop 
loop7    7:7    0    0B  0 loop 
sda      8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0  100G  0 part /
```

```
sudo mount | grep -i loop
sudo cat /proc/mounts | grep -i loop
sudo cat /etc/fstab | grep loop
sudo lsof /dev/loop0
```

No output.

```
sudo dmesg | grep loop
```

```
[    0.572944] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4390.12 BogoMIPS (lpj=8780240)
[   15.902123] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop...
[   15.909809] loop: module loaded
[   15.915496] systemd[1]: modprobe@loop.service: Deactivated successfully.
[   15.915643] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop.
```

- This never happened in Debian 11 (`bullseye`).
- This was introduced in Debian 12 (`bookworm`).

How are these loop devices created? What is the purpose of these loop devices?

Comment: Have you read man pages? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html

Answer (score 1):

These are [loop devices](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html), created by the `loop` module. They are used to present any underlying storage as a block device; typically, this is [used to mount a file system stored in an image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476050/86440).

A few of them are instantiated by default, but they remain empty until they are associated with underlying storage. `lsblk` doesn’t show empty devices, `lsblk --all` does.

This behaviour isn’t directly related to the switch from Debian 11 to 12; it happens on Debian 11 too, if the `loop` module is loaded.

Comment: How many you get depends on the `max_loop` module parameter (see `/sys/module/loop/parameters/max_loop` for  the value which can be changed at loading time or as kernel cmdline parameter when the module is builtin, not run time)

Comment: The `modprobe@loop.service` seems to be dependency of `systemd-repart.service`