# Why there are 3 loop devices on my system right after boot?

Tags: linux, loop-device

I'll start this question by listing all drives available on my system right after the login into my Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 89,1 MiB, 93454336 bytes, 182528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 89,1 MiB, 93429760 bytes, 182480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 202,9 MiB, 212713472 bytes, 415456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 989573D5-37E7-437A-B680-9410F7234A94

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048     194559     192512    94M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 194560 1000214527 1000019968 476,9G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B05FAE90-8E4B-4CCC-AC77-D35D4B260C8A

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1026048   1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3    1288192 459608774 458320583 218,6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  459610112 461398015   1787904   873M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  461398016 485992447  24594432  11,7G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  485992448 488396799   2404352   1,2G Windows recovery environment
```

---

Here, I should probably add, I don't even know what a loop device is. I just mount a lot of disks daily, make images of them, work with those and such. I have noticed those loop devices 0, 1, 2 as of this moment, but they might very well be here for ages, maybe I just did not pay attention to them, due to work stress.

---

Listing them does not reveal when they originated probably as I see today's date:

```
# ll /dev/loop[012]

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 7, 0 Nov 13  2019 /dev/loop0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 7, 1 Nov 13  2019 /dev/loop1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 7, 2 Nov 13  2019 /dev/loop2
```

---

Why they're on my system even if I reboot? Isn't that strange?

Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=f1fc7345-be7a-4c6b-9559-fc6e2d445bfa    /               ext4     errors=remount-ro                0    1
UUID=4966-E925                               /boot/efi       vfat     umask=0077                       0    1
none                                         /ramdisk        tmpfs    size=1G,mode=0777                0    0
UUID=01D480EF7EDA45C0                        /mnt/windows    ntfs     nosuid,nodev,nofail,noexec,rw    0    0
```

---

How do I get more information about these 3 loop devices?

I tried `fdisk` now:

```
# fdisk /dev/loop0

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old squashfs signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xc54bc258.

Command (m for help): v
Remaining 182527 unallocated 512-byte sectors.

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/loop0: 89,1 MiB, 93454336 bytes, 182528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc54bc258
```

---

I've already regenerated my `initramfs` image with no change, they're still there after reboot.

---

I'd rather know more about them before actually trying to delete them.

---

Questions and answers to comments:

> Why are you not as concerned by the various `/dev/tty*` devices as by the `loop` devices?

Well, this is a tough question, as I don't know exactly what those `tty` devices purpose is. So, I guess *ignorance is bliss*, sort of speak.

> Why do you want to delete the `/dev/loop*` devices specifically?

I said I want to know more about them, to investigate what they contain, well, and as per `fdisk` output, they do not, correction, contain any partition table. What's more, these `loop` devices are not present on any other Linux I am directly working with.

---

It seems, it has some relation to Snap daemon.

```
# losetup -a

/dev/loop1: [66306]:6161256 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8039.snap)
/dev/loop2: [66306]:6160663 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap)
/dev/loop0: [66306]:6160545 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1049.snap)

# losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                           DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop1         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8039.snap   0     512
/dev/loop2         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap   0     512
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1049.snap    0     512
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of `/dev/loop*` devices doesn’t necessarily indicate anything; some systems pre-populate them, others don’t. However, if they show up in `fdisk -l`’s output, that means they’ve been set up to provide a loop device over either a file or another block device.

You can see what loop devices are set up, and what they “loop” over, by running

```
losetup -l
```

as root. In your case, the devices are being used to access Snap volumes;

```
snap list
```

will list the running Snaps on your system (apparently VLC and the core Snap). See [the Ubuntu Snap tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage) for a brief introduction.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up, I do still have, however a *small-ish* question: What did you mean by "if they show up in fdisk -l’s output..."

Comment: Because I did mount some disk images, for evidence with a command like this: `mount -o ro,offset=$(( 512 * 2048 )) memtest86-usb-v8.2.img mnt1/` which I don't remember how it ended up, I copy-pasted it from the history.

Comment: For example, on one of my systems, there are eight `/dev/loop` devices by default; right now, only one of them is actually used, and only that one shows up in `fdisk -l`’s output (or `lesetup -l`), the rest can be ignored. `mount -o` [uses `/dev/loopX` behind the scenes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466940/86440).