# Partitions /dev/loopXX

Tags: debian, fdisk, partition-table

While I was checking my disk space today with `df -h` I noticed all these /dev/loopXX partitions which I don't know what they really are.

[image]

What are them? Should I keep it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there are 3 loop devices on my system right after boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551882/why-there-are-3-loop-devices-on-my-system-right-after-boot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/loop` devices are devices which make regular files viewed as block devices. They are managed by `losetup`. I invite you to type `losetup -l` to see which is mapped to which.

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047456/why-are-all-snaps-being-mounted-and-listed-as-block-devices-or-partitions-for-ub about why snap creates them.

Answer (score 5):

These are [loop devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device), files mapped as a block devices. In your case these are created and used by [snap packages](https://snapcraft.io/) on your system and you should just ignore them.